# If every transaction has a "Transaction Public Key" field, why is this public key repeated on the "extra" field?

Tags: transaction-data

I understand that the `extra` field in a transaction is a "freestyle" field, but after exploring several transactions on xmrchain, I noticed that the *transaction public key* tends to be repeated inside `extra` despite already being indicated in its dedicated field.

Example:

`Tx hash`: 397d7b4f155214420cd168810e086a6d34f92a89723b961eedb58645bf872c92

`Tx prefix hash`: 904b7a8b6424c708301ea903cb7a3474374f67e56f191c0a371d60a2d53a7a4c

`Tx public key`: **3e6442e081c5ff7e7fd9277ebd1f4f7e74bc974a53d20b36a99f5474b6424e0c**

`Extra`: 01**3e6442e081c5ff7e7fd9277ebd1f4f7e74bc974a53d20b36a99f5474b6424e0c**020901029c7a5118ae58f5

Any idea why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If every transaction has a "Transaction Public Key" field, why is this public key repeated on the "extra" field?

The transaction public key(s) are *only* in the tx extra field, not repeated. Plural because there can be more than one per transaction.

> ...but after exploring several transactions on xmrchain, I noticed that the transaction public key tends to be repeated inside extra despite already being indicated in its dedicated field.

It's not repeated, it's *only* in the tx extra field. The fact a block explorer *displays* it in multiple places is down to that implementation.